# Не могу понять, нужно ли делать override для GetHashCode() для объекта кастомного класса

Tags: c#

Класс:

```
public class Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Type { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }        
    public string? Warehouse { get; set; }
}
```

Не могу понять, стоит ли делать override для GetHashCode() в своем классе? Например, перемножить длину строк всех строковых свойств с интовым свойством

В программе из листа с объектами данного класса (который не должен меняться) формируется HashSet для дальнейшего быстрого удаления какого-то определенного объекта из него. В списке могут попадаться одинаковые объекты по всем свойствам, кроме Warehouse. Есть ли шанс, что сгенерируется одинаковый HashCode для двух объектов с одним отличающимся полем и удалится не тот объект?

Проверял сгенированные коды, совпадений пока не нашел, по F12 не написано в комментариях, как конкретно вычисляется

Comment: Помимо GetHashCode также необходимо переопределять Equals. Не думаю, что для разных (по значениям полей) объектов сгенерируется одинаковый хэш-код. Переопределение GetHashCode, на сколько я понимаю, предназначено для исключения использования рефлексии и настраиваемого поведения сравнения. После добавления объекта в HashSet он не должен изменяться, либо его нужно извлекать, изменять и опять добавлять. [Статья по теме](https://liamelliott.me/coding/getHashCode)

Comment: Там же где-то даже готовый сниппет вроде предлагается для этого. Переопределять нужно, чтобы поиск в `HashSet` работал эффективнее. Хэш-код служит для быстрого поиска, потом если хэш-коды совпадают, всё-равно делается проверка `Equals` (которую тоже нужно переопределять). Поэтому не качественный (но детерминированный) хэш-код не так чтобы всё сломает, но замедлит операции с хэш-сетом. Теоретически он может хоть константу возвращать, тогда всегда будет выполняться проверка через `Equals`. Ничего не сломается, но будет очень неэффективно.

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Код, о котором речь вы оставили в секрете.